# If I return a given value from Reader#read(), what does it mean for chars after that offset?

Tags: java, io

Suppose you are writing a reader which removes all instances of a character (let's say that you are removing 'x'.)

You might write that like this:

```
public class ExampleReader extends FilterReader {
    public ExampleReader(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
            if (ch != 'x') {
                return ch;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int charsRead = in.read(cbuf, off, len);
        if (charsRead == -1) {
            return -1;
        }

        // srcPos will always be >= dstPos
        int charsRemoved = 0;
        int srcEnd = off + charsRead;
        for (int srcPos = off, dstPos = off; srcPos < srcEnd; srcPos++, dstPos++) {
            char ch = cbuf[srcPos];
            if (ch == 'x') {
                dstPos--;
                charsRemoved++;
            } else {
                cbuf[dstPos] = cbuf[srcPos];
            }
        }

        return charsRead - charsRemoved;
    }
}
```

In code review, another developer claims that if you return less than `len`, you're not supposed to have written any characters outside of the slice you read, according to the return value. However, this is not mentioned in the docs at all - they just say that the `len` value passed in is the maximum number of chars to read.

My own view is that if you are passed `len`, then you have been given permission to write anything you want in `off..off+len` and if you happen to return less, then you're not making any guarantees about the contents of the rest of the array. Likewise, if I were calling a reader, I wouldn't assume that the data outside of the range which was returned is meaningful to read.

Who is right?

(As a side note, what I actually implemented was line separator normalisation, \r\n and others to \n. I was sure that something so common would have been in Guava, but it didn't seem to be. Is it really that rare a task?)

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc for InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) says "these bytes will be stored in elements b[off] through b[off+k-1], leaving elements b[off+k] through b[off+len-1] unaffected." It's not reiterated for `Reader.read()` but it clearly should be.

Comment: I was aware of the rule being on InputStream.read... it's just that when something is absent, sometimes it's absent for a reason.

Comment: Could be. I'm not aware of any.